# How to optimize OrangeFS?

Tags: file-io, parallel-processing, filesystems

I have built a parallel file system (cluster) with OrangeFS. I am new in this area. How could I optimize it? It seems that RAID and Logical Volume Management (LVM) are good choices, but I cannot find any tutorial or doc about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raid 0 works. The instruction is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID